# $\mathbf{Z}$-points of quasi-projective schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $U\subset\mathbf{P}^n_{\mathbf{Z}}$ be an open subscheme such that the smooth morphism $U\to\text{Spec}(\mathbf{Z})$ is surjective. Suppose $U(\mathbf{Q})\neq\varnothing$ and $U(\mathbf{Z}_p)\neq\varnothing$ for all primes $p$.

> Do we have $U(\mathbf{Z})\neq\varnothing$?

The answer is probably "no", but I could benefit from related references.

> Does there exist a finite extension $K/\mathbf{Q}$ such that, if $R$ is the integral closure in $K$ of $\mathbf{Z}$, then $U(R)\neq\varnothing$, and what can one say about $R$? (for example, how ramified is it?)

This question came up while reading through this [paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.1863.pdf) of Autissier.

> Do we at least have $U(\overline{\mathbf{Z}})^{\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q})}\neq\varnothing$, and under what conditions on $U$ can we deduce $U(\mathbf{Z})\neq\varnothing$? (presumably some condition on the codimension/singularities of the complement).

A variant of the same question, with $U(\mathbf{Q})\neq \varnothing$ replaced by $U(\overline{\mathbf{Z}})\neq\varnothing$.

> Does there exist a finite extension $K/\mathbf{Q}$ such that, if $R$ is the integral closure in $K$ of $\mathbf{Z}$, then $U(R)\neq\varnothing$ if $U(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ and $U(\overline{\mathbf{Z}})$ are nonempty for all $p$, and what can one say about $R$?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  That fails if $U$ is the complement in $\mathbb{P}^1$ of the union of three pairwise disjoint sections.

Comment: I guess the second question has a positive answer for that open (already over the Eisenstein integers).

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you a lot for your answers. Is there any reference that I can read for the second? I would like to generalize it to all number fields/rings as opposed to $\mathbf{Z}$. So is $U(\mathbf{Q})$ and $U(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ are all nonempty, then $U(R)$ also is, with $R$ the ring of integers of $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$? If I read this right.

Comment: In my second comment I only meant the open in my first comment, not *every* open.  Actually I think a better choice of $U$ is something like the complement in $\mathbb{P}^1$ of $\{[1,0],[1,2n],[0,1]\}$ for any nonzero integer $n$.  My original choice has no local $2$-adic points (oops!), but this choice does have $p$-adic points for every prime $p$, even though it has no global points.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks for your answer. If $U$ intersects scheme-theoretically the standard torus in $\mathbf{P}^1_{\mathbf{Z}}$ and if the intersection surjects onto $\text{Spec}(\mathbf{Z})$, can't one use Thm.0 in the linked paper to get a $\mathbf{Z}$-point though? In that case, your $U$ would have one. I must be missing something. Thanks

Comment: Rumely produces points after extension to the ring of integers of a bigger number field, not over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jason Starr points out, $U = \mathbf P^1{\setminus}\{[1{:}0],[1{:}4],[0{:}1]\}$ is a counterexample to the first question:

- It has a $\mathbf Z[1/3]$-point $[1{:}1]$ and a $\mathbf Z[1/2]$-point $[1{:}2]$, so $U(\mathbf Q) \neq \varnothing$ and $U(\mathbf Z_p)\neq\varnothing$ for all primes $p$;
- But it does not have a $\mathbf Z$-point: such a point is of the form $[a{:}b]$ with $a,b \in \mathbf Z$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Then $a \neq 0$ since $[a{:}b] \neq [0{:}1]$, so it is not possible that both $b$ and $4a-b$ are a unit in $\mathbf Z$. Then there exists a prime $p$ dividing either $b$ or $4a-b$. If $p \mid b$, then $[a{:}b]$ intersects $[1{:}0]$ above $p$, and if $p \mid 4a-b$, then $[a{:}b]$ intersects $[1{:}4] = [a{:}4a]$ above $p$. So $[a{:}b]$ never lands entirely in $U$.

The answer to the second question is positive: following the references in Autissier's paper quickly leads to the following result of Skolem [Sko34] (see also [MB89, 1.1] — I was unable to access the original source [Sko34] at the moment).

**Theorem.** *Let $p \in \bar{\mathbf Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a polynomial. Then the following are equivalent:*

- *there exist $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in \bar{\mathbf Z}$ such that $p(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a unit;*
- *$p$ is primitive.*

This means that a standard open $U = D(f) \subseteq \mathbf A^n_{\mathbf Z}$ has an $\mathcal O_K$-point for some number field $K$ if and only if $f$ is primitive, i.e. if and only if $U \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Z$ is surjective. If $f$ is moreover homogeneous, then the standard open $D_+(f) \subseteq \mathbf P^{n-1}_{\mathbf Z}$ therefore also has an $\mathcal O_K$-point.

Now if $U \subseteq \mathbf P^n_{\mathbf Z}$ is any open such that $U \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Z$ is surjective, then it contains a standard open with the same property: for each component $Z_i$ of the complement $Z$ of $U$, pick a primitive polynomial $f_i$ in the homogeneous ideal of $Z_i$. Setting $f = \prod_i f_i$ and $V = D_+(f) \subseteq U$ does the trick. Since $V$ contains an $\mathcal O_K$-point for some number field $K$, so does $U$.

(This is all subsumed by Rumely's theorem, but in this case we really only need Skolem's version!)

If you want to make this more effective, you have to look into the proofs of Skolem and Rumely.

---

**References.**

[MB89]  L. Moret-Bailly, [*Groupes de Picard et problèmes de Skolem, I*](https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1581). Ann. Sci. Éc. Norm. Supér. (4) **22**.2 (1989), p. 161-179. [ZBL0704.14014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0704.14014).

[Sko34]  Th. Skolem, *Lösung gewisser Gleichungen in ganzen algebraischen Zahlen, insbesondere in Einheiten*. Skr. Norske Vid.-Akad. **10** (1935), p. 1-19. [ZBL0011.19701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0011.19701).

Comment: I also vaguely remember a related theorem by Brumer (who used to show up to Johan’s seminar).

Comment: For some effective results, see [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.2001.021/html).

Comment: Thanks! This together with the paper linked by @LaurentMoret-Bailly were exactly what I needed.